# WP7 background tasks

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, settings, task, agent

When [reading about background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), I am confused

1. Windows Phone 7 allow using Scheduled Task to register a background
   agent. So what is the difference between Scheduled Task and
   background agent ?
2. There are 2 types of Schduled Task and I use both of them

> ```
> ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask); 
>
> ScheduledActionService.Add(resourceIntensiveTask);
> ```

In MSDN noted that

> Description field is required and is used to describe the agent to the
>   user in the background tasks Settings page on the device

But in the Background tasks settings, I see **only periodic task**

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A task is the container that is managet by the operating system and runs at the appoined time. It runs the agent witch is the actual code payload.

take a look of [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Mango-Jump-Start/Mango-Jump-Start-06-Windows-Phone-Multi-tasking--Background-Tasks?format=html5)